# Volley UnknownHostExeption

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem with using Volley. I'm trying to send request to site  `http://lawbite_api.codebnb.me` but results differ from phone to phone (depends on Android version). For some reason on Android 6 all OK, but on Android 4.4 I'm getting `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

Here is stacktrace:

```
 com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://lawbite_api.codebnb.me/api/login
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
 at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://lawbite_api.codebnb.me/api/login
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:279)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:264)
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
 at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
```

Comment: it can be internet issue

Comment: @VivekMishra No, internet is OK. I can send request to something like google.com and succeed

Comment: is there one of these an emulator?

Comment: Try without the underscore in the subdomain, there could be something odd on Android 4.4

Comment: Its giving message "405 Method Not Allowed". Check for post method with required values

Comment: @AshishJohn Yes, if you will go view browser, it will give 405, because your   it's requires POST request

Comment: @Ryan It's definitely something odd in 4.4, domain like google.com (without underscore) will work fine, but my domain doesn't work. Is there some workaround?

Comment: make sure your api or domain `http://lawbite_api.codebnb.me/api/login` is working.

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha it's working for Android 6, but not for 4.4. I think server is pretty much ok

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to not use an underscore in the subdomain part of the hostname. It's probably something to do with the hostname rules in Android 4.4 (and probably lower).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think url will change as per API level in Volley. I have already use same URL for all devices with API greater than Android 4.4 and there is no issue regarding to URL there is something else. Please provide Volley request code

Comment: Problem was in using underscore in the url. Pre-lolipop devices use different library for executing http requests. When I connected OKHTTP 3 to Volley it allowed me to access sites with underscores.